# Usb to Ethernet driver compilation on linux kernel 3.0 and above

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I cross compiled USB to Ethernet driver in the Linux Kernel source tree at `drivers/net/usb/smsc75xx.c` for Android Kernel 3.0.8. Cross compilation worked fine as well as inserting the Kernel module using `insmod`. But the ethernet interface does not show up nor `dmesg` detects module's insertion (using `insmod`) or removal (using `rmmod`). Since `dmesg` is silent about its insertion or removal, something seems not right?

How to debug this non-working driver in a non-verbose environment?

Comment: somebody is reducing this guy's points for no reason. I have seen million of similar posts which are +ve repped. I guess there seems to be some bias!!!

Comment: Sounds like you are facing a difference in API's between kernel versions.  Can you not find a version of the driver already intended for (or included with) 3.x?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, There is no version of the driver for kernel version 3.0 and above. I am looking if it is possible that Kernel 3.0 and above can be fooled i.e., driver compiled from kernel 2.6 can be hacked to work with newer kernel. Any thoughts, ideas ??

Comment: Are you sure?  There's an smsc75xx driver in the mainline kernel.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet for the edits. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the drivers/net/usb/smsc75xx.c. It seems the driver is already in the upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually need to compile this for Android Kernel. You are true that it is in the kernel source tree. I was able to compile it and get smsc75xx.ko file. When i tried to load it using insmod, i got "insmod: can't insert 'smsc75xx.ko': unknown symbol in module or invalid parameter"

Comment: I was able to get install the smsc75xx.ko module but ethernet interface eth0 does not show u. Dmesg also does not show any messages when i do "insmod smsc75xx.ko". Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: If you have the kernel version which works I suggest to boot it and run lsusb -n. When you get ID of your device, check if it in the driver. It might be that certain device requires quirks. I didn't check the driver though.

Comment: ! I don't see the -n option with lsusb on Ubuntu 14.04. How to check the id of the device in the driver? By the way, lsusb without any switch does not show anything related to this driver but dmesg does

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I messed option with lspci. Anyway, what does dmesg tell you about the device?

Comment: Andy! dmesg does not show any message related to this device when i "insmod" it or "rmmod" it. There is no activity in dmesg log related to this device. This is what i am not able to debug until now. I hope i can get past this and educate the wider community as well. Thanks again for being persistent. See my second comment above for reference.

Comment: Ok, so, have you checked your device on *working* kernel? That's the point you can start from. It's intereting output of lsusb and dmesg in that case. Or you unable to get it working in any kernel you have?

Comment: yes it works on my Ubuntu's linux kernel. No problem at all. But when i cross compile it for Android kernel and insert it using insmod on Android, it loads fine (insmod does not complain) but dmesg is silent about its detection.lsmod shows it being loaded as module. I have cross compiled other device driver for Android and it worked fine. Dmesg detected it when i plugged it in using insmod or removed it using rmmod. But how do i debug kernel modules that get loaded fine but neither work nor dmesg captures their presence or error

Comment: Are you sure your Android device is in USB host mode? And also you may add `initcall_debug` to the kernel command line in order to see what happened to your module.